# angular 4 passing an object containing other objects into FormBuilder.group function leads to a strange form behavior

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms

Creating a nested form made up of the following "nested object" (Building):

```
export class Building{
  id: number = 0;
  doorsCount: number = 0;
  description: string = '';
  address: Address = new Address();
  buildingType: BuildingType = new BuildingType();
}

export class Address{
  id: number = 0;
  description: string = '';
}

export class BuildingType{
  id: number = 0;
  description: string = '';
}
```

As you can see `Building` class contains other classes like `Address` and `BuildingType` which also have other properties such as `id` and `description`.

When creating the form I used the following code at the component ts file:

```
buildingForm: FormGroup;

construct(private fb: FormBuilder){
 this.buildingForm = this.createBuildingFG(new Building);
}

createBuildingFG(building: Building){
  let formGroup : FormGroup;
  formGroup = this.fb.group(building);

  // Because object of type "building" contain properties of non-primitive 
  // types such as object Address and BuildingType I think the following 
  // additional lines are required. 

  formGroup.controls.address = this.fb.group(building.address);
  formGroup.controls.buildingType = this.fb.group(building.buildingType);

  return formGroup;
}
```

And this is how the form is bound to the HTML template:

```
<form [formGroup]="buildingForm">
    <label>
        Door count: 
        <input formControlName="doorsCount" >
    </label>
    <label>
        Building description: 
        <input formControlName="description" >
    </label>
    <label formGroupName="address">
        Address: 
        <input formControlName="description"  >
    </label>
    <label formGroupName="buildingType">
         Building type: 
        <input formControlName="description" >
    </label>    
</form>
```

Now the problem arises when I output the value of the whole form which do not really update according to what is being typed in the nested field controls that are inside a `formGroup` such as address or buildingType. Otherwise it updates normally.

This is how the value is output

```
<div>
   {{buildingForm.value | json}}
</div>
```

However, if `createBuildingFG` function was done differently and every `formControl` was created explicitly with out just passing an entire object, the form acts normally. Example:

```
createBuildingFG(building: Building){
  let formGroup : FormGroup;
  formGroup = this.fb.group({
    doorsCount: '',
    description: '',
    address: this.fb.group({ description: ''}),
    buildingType: this.fb.group({ description: ''})
  });

  return formGroup;
}
```

Anyone can explain what is going on? Obviously to avoid doing this tedious task of explicitly defining each element of the `fromGroup`, one would want to just pass an entire object.

Comment: At a guess, because the initial construction does things you're not subsequently overriding. Why not build a copy of the object *then* pass the whole thing to the form builder? With destructuring it should be reasonably neat.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe that's an interesting approach. Can you please give me a hint on how to do destructuring in this case. Its rather confusing for me.

Comment: Personally I'd avoid passing the data object as configuration object to `FormBuilder.group`. It may works for the most trivial example (like a plain object with all primitive fields, and no validation required), but most of the time you'll need more than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned in comments

> because the initial construction does things you're not subsequently
>   overriding.

So what are the things?

When angular create new instance of FormGroup it calls `_setUpControls` method

```typescript
export class FormGroup extends AbstractControl {
  constructor(
      public controls: {[key: string]: AbstractControl},
      validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn|ValidatorFn[]|AbstractControlOptions|null,
      asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn|AsyncValidatorFn[]|null) {
    super(
        coerceToValidator(validatorOrOpts),
        coerceToAsyncValidator(asyncValidator, validatorOrOpts));
    this._initObservables();
    this._setUpdateStrategy(validatorOrOpts);
    this._setUpControls();  <--------------
```

and now let's look at the method:

```typescript
/** @internal */
_setUpControls(): void {
  this._forEachChild((control: AbstractControl) => {
     control.setParent(this);
     control._registerOnCollectionChange(this._onCollectionChange);
  });
}
```

As we can see each item of controls sets parent and registers some event but you don't do that.

The following code should work:

```typescript
formGroup = this.fb.group(building);
formGroup.controls.address = formGroup.controls.buildingType = null;
formGroup.registerControl('address', this.fb.group(building.address));
formGroup.registerControl('buildingType', this.fb.group(building.buildingType));
```

or you can use recursion to do it working:

```typescript
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
  this.buildingForm = this.createFormGroup(new Building);
}

createFormGroup(obj: any) {
  let formGroup: { [id: string]: AbstractControl; } = {};

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    formGroup[key] = obj[key] instanceof Object ? this.createFormGroup(obj[key]) : new FormControl(obj[key]);
  });

  return this.fb.group(formGroup);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I used the non recursion approach.